# In Terraform for AWS, can I do a retry on a resource creation?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform 0.12.x

I'm attaching an EBS volume to my EC2

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "dev_xvdf" {
  device_name  = "/dev/xvdf"
  instance_id  = aws_instance.jenkins_master.id
  skip_destroy = var.skip_att_ebs_destroy
  volume_id    = var.ebs_id
}
```

But I get

```
module.ec2_blue.aws_volume_attachment.dev_xvdf: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.ec2_blue.aws_volume_attachment.dev_xvdf: Still creating... [20s elapsed]

Error: Error waiting for Volume (vol-123456abcedf) to attach to Instance: i-123456abcdef, error: unexpected state 'detached', wanted target 'attached'. last error: %!s(<nil>)
```

Ca I do a retry, or increase a timeout?

Comment: Do you know why its failing to attach? Can you attach it in AWS console to verify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retries and timeouts in Terraform are handled (or not) by the provider as an implementation detail, and so you can't control them *directly* in the Terraform configuration unless the provider developer exposed a way to do so.

Some resource types follow a convention of accepting [a `timeouts` block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#operation-timeouts) to optionally shorten or extend the timeout on a particular operation:

```
 timeouts {
   create = "1m"
 }
```

The `aws_volume_attachment` doesn't seem to support this, instead [hard-coding a five-minute timeout](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/43553f0e8e2c0648c94c3c753fc9df85bae6175e/aws/resource_aws_volume_attachment.go#L132-L146).

However, we can see in your case that the problem doesn't seem to actually *be* the timeout, because the operation failed after only 20 seconds and it seems like the problem was that it entered an unexpected status rather than that it took to long to reach the *expected* status.

I'm not super familiar with the state machine for volume attachments, but from reading the AWS provider code it seems like the provider expects the attachment to initially be in the "attaching" state and then eventually reach the "attached" state. It failed here because it actually entered the "detached" state, which is neither the state the provider considers to mean "pending" nor the one meaning "succeeded".

With all of that said, I think this is a real error rather than a timeout. I don't know what is causing the error, but you may be able to find out by attempting to perform the same operation manually using either the web console or the AWS CLI. If you're able to gather more information doing that, I expect someone will be able to give a more helpful answer to a new question including that additional information.

Comment: Great to know. You addressed the timeout question, how about retries?

Comment: I meant to say, if I execute the plan again, the volume will attach.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a situation where a "retry" in the usual sense of the term would help, because the request to _begin attaching the volume_ succeeded, starting an asynchronous operation that then somehow failed. Terraform is only picking it up at all because it polls the `Describe...` endpoint to wait for the async operation to complete. I don't know of any way to ask the provider to try making a new request if the async operation fails to complete.

Comment: Because the provider uses an asynchronous call for this, the provider is supposed to handle errors of this kind, so I would report this as a bug in the provider.